# Google Spreadsheets API removes underscore

Tags: java, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Spreadsheets API with a list-based feed. When I get the tags values - with getCustomElements().getTags() - I get them without underscore. For example: parent_id becomes parentid.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have only been able to get "true" column names by using the cell feed.

```
<?php

    // given $spreadsheetKey, $worksheetId, $spreadsheetService...

    $qry = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_CellQuery();
    $qry->setSpreadsheetKey($spreadsheetKey);
    $qry->setWorksheetId($worksheetId);
    $qry->setMinCol(1);
    $qry->setMaxCol(null);
    $qry->setMinRow(1);
    $qry->setMaxRow(1);

    $cellFeed = $spreadsheetService->getCellFeed($qry);

    foreach ($cellFeed as $cellEntry)
    {
        $columnNumber = $cellEntry->cell->getColumn();
        $columnLabel  = $cellEntry->cell->getText();
        echo "Column $columnNumber is labeled $columnLabel<br>\n";
    }

?>
```